# Maven dependency in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am trying to use jersey API and this is my first maven project.

I have 2 maven dependency problems that look like this:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
ArtifactTransferException: Failure to transfer org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1 from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Missing artifact org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar:1.0.1
```

How should I go about to fix this?

Comment: Try deleting the existing local contents at your repository folder. should be on your user  ${user.home}/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2 . Then do a Maven -> Update project and Force Update of Snapshots/Releases

Comment: I am not sure where do I need to delete the contents from but I I did force update of snapshots ,It did not fix it.

Comment: If you are using Windows they should be inside your User folder (Windows 7 example c:\Users\<username\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your failed downloads from

For windows:

```
cd %userprofile%\.m2\repository
for /r %i in (*.lastUpdated) do del %i
```

Then rightclick on your project in eclipse and choose Maven->Update Dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your response. Could you please explain which command line I need to use and where do I access it from ?

Comment: open the command prompt and got to location of the pom.xml of your project and run mvn clean install


or

go to the .m2 folder in your user profile folder and delete the folder of  mention jar (org.glassfish.hk2:osgi-resource-locator:jar) and go to eclipse, rightclick on your project in eclipse and choose Maven->Update Dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions

1. Delete your repo in home folder then build with force Update Snapshot option
2. Copy paste link in error trace into your browser if didnt work you have to create `settings.xml` file in your repo home folder and set proxy if you are using them